# To show that $\mathcal{L}_{0}$ is a $\pi$-system

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

For $A\in\mathcal{L}_{0}$, let $\mathcal{L}_{A}=\{B\subset\Omega:A\cap B\in\mathcal{L}_{0}\}$.
To show that $\mathcal{L}_{0}$ is a $\pi$-system is to show that $\mathcal{L}_{A}\supset\mathcal{L}_{0}$
for every $A\in\mathcal{L}_{0}$

$\Omega$: denote a universal set.

My question is why they are equivalent. i.e., why $\mathcal{L}_{A}\supset\mathcal{L}_{0}$
for every $A\in\mathcal{L}_{0}$  implies $\mathcal{L}_{0}$ is a $\pi$-system

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the question is.  What is it that you are trying to show?  What are your basic definitions?  What have you tried?

Comment: @XanderHenderson . thanks! I edited. I cannot see from the definition of $\pi$-system right away.